# Value in array column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following query:

```
select tracks.id
     , JSON_EXTRACT(tracks.sources, "$[*].origin") as c 
  from tracks
```

Which leads to the following result set:

| id | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1260631 | ["itunes_old_db"] |
| 1260632 | ["amazon"] |
| 1260633 | ["amazon"] |
| 1260634 | ["apple"] |
| 1260635 | ["itunes_old_db", "apple"] |

And I want only the following results by checking if either "apple" or "itunes_old_db
" is in `c` column:

| id | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1260631 | ["itunes_old_db"] |
| 1260634 | ["apple"] |
| 1260635 | ["itunes_old_db", "apple"] |

I tried several things, but none have worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried FIND_IN_SET() in the WHERE clause ? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: *Which leads to the following result set* Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.